# Flag undermenu hidden when question doesn't have any comments

Tags: bug, mobile-web, mobile-safari

When flagging a question on the mobile site and the question doe not have any comments, a part of the flag submenu gets hidden by a textbox.
iPod 4G/iOS 6.1 (10B144) using Safari.
[Screenshot http://puu.sh/81NXm.jpg](http://puu.sh/81NXm.jpg)

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate. Sorry for that

Comment: @Kimmax Ah, sorry for being careless. I couldn't see the image since the URL was blocked in my office.